# Finding IP address using NMAP6.47 for Raspberry pi B+

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh, raspbian-wheezy, static-ip

I need to find IP address of my Raspberry PI to further use in Putty, I have connected the ethernet. 
I made changes in cmdline.text file of the Raspbian wheezy OS, allocated IP address to it (ip=169.254.210.40::169.254.210.55), based on IP v-4 address of my ethernet adapter was (169.254.210.55) which all I followed from a video on youtube. 
When I tried to ping the address no response came. Hence I am doing something wrong.

All I want is to run my pi on laptop, I have putty and Xming installed but without knowing the IP of pi I can't proceed further.
Also this is the first boot( I mean I have not installed anything using a monitor and HDMI)
DESPERATELY NEED HELP!!!

Comment: 169.254 is a link local address which is not going to work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/169.254 You need to use an address of your network. If you use the standard Pi setup it will find one from DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nmap -O -T4 169.254.210.40-55
```

You will recognize the Raspberry Pi through the MAC address which should be recognized as *Raspberry Pi Foundation* - See:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-19 19:05 CET
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.5
Host is up (0.00056s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:AE:36:D7 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see
http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
```

Comment: As per my answer above this will not work with a link local address (unless the Pi is directly connected to the PC), and even then there are other problems.